# Default front page not showing https

Tags: 8

My website URL shows in browser https

But on https://test.com/admin/config/system/site-information

[image]

It's showing http.

What will be cause of this? Server configuration (apache)?

Does it relate to Base URL?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The field prefix is populated by the [`RequestContext:: getCompleteBaseUrl()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Routing%21RequestContext.php/function/RequestContext%3A%3AgetCompleteBaseUrl/8.5.x) method, the underlying property, `completeBaseUrl`, is assigned from `$GLOBALS['base_url']` [if it's set](https://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/tree/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Routing/RequestContext.php?id=8.5.3#n37).

You'll have to test that out to see if that's the case for you, because you might have a web stack configuration that causes Drupal only to see unencrypted requests (e.g. HTTPS only handled at your load balancer / proxy server level), thus displaying the HTTP base.

Comment: We r not setting `$GLOBALS['base_url']`. What can be solution?